# 1 iframe 2 button's with onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been working on this about 3 hours now.. I can't figure out why it's not working.

The first button should open an iframe, which it does. The second should do the same. Somewhy it's not willing to do so!

Here is my code:

```
<body>

<input type="button" id="knopSql1" type="submit" value="1e Klasse"></input>

<script>

document.getElementById('knopSql1').onclick = function() {
var iframe = frames[0] || document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src='http://www.example.com/sql.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

</script>

<input type="button" id="knopSql2" type="submit" value="2e Klasse"></input>

<script>

document.getElementById('knopSql2').onclick = function() {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src'http://www.example.com/sql2.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Fredrick A. @K D I love you guys for eternity for that! Yet.. I feel like a idiot for not noticing xd

Comment: @Fredrik A. @K D I have another question. How can I get my second button work just like the first. That it opens just a single iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code of second script

```
iframe.src'http://www.example.com/sql2.php';
```

Should be

```
iframe.src ='http://www.example.com/sql2.php';
```

You are missing '=' operator

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the = sign in the last block of code.
You wrote:

```
iframe.src'...';
```

instead of

```
iframe.src = '...';
```

By the way, this would take way less code in jQuery :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FredrikAugust/bxH2T/)

EDIT: Sorry, did not see that someone answered before me!